# Invalidate queries doesn't work [React-Query]

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-query

I'm trying to invalidate queries every times users press button "likes" to refresh all queries but without success so far despite following the docs.

I have a component that get data :

```
  const {
    data: resultsEnCours,
    isLoading,
    isError,
  } = useQueryGetEvents("homeencours", { currentEvents: true });
```

This is a custom hook which look like this :

```
const useQueryGetEvents = (nameQuery, params, callback) => {
  const [refetch, setRefetch] = React.useState(null);
  const refetchData = () => setRefetch(Date.now()); // => manual refresh
  const { user } = React.useContext(AuthContext);
  const { location } = React.useContext(SearchContext);

  const { isLoading, isError, data } = useQuery(
    [nameQuery, refetch],
    () => getFromApi(user.token, "getEvents", { id_user: user.infoUser.id, ...params }),
    // home params => "started", "upcoming", "participants"
    {
      select: React.useCallback(({ data }) => filterAndSortByResults(data, location, callback), []),
    }
  );

  return { data, isLoading, isError, refetchData };
};

export default useQueryGetEvents;
```

And I have another component "ButtonLikeEvent" which allow the user to like or unlike an event:

```
import { useMutation, useQueryClient } from "react-query";
import { postFromApi } from "../../api/routes"; 
...other imports


const ButtonLikeEvent = ({ item, color = "#fb3958" }) => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  const {
    user: {
      token,
      infoUser: { id },
    },
  } = React.useContext(AuthContext);

  const [isFavorite, setIsFavorite] = React.useState(item.isFavorite);
  const likeEventMutation = useMutation((object) => postFromApi(token, "postLikeEvent", object));
  const dislikeEventMutation = useMutation((object) =>
    postFromApi(token, "postDislikeEvent", object)
  );

  const callApi = () => {
    if (!isFavorite) {
      likeEventMutation.mutate(
        { id_events: item.id, id_user: id },
        {
          onSuccess() {
            queryClient.invalidateQueries();
            console.log("liked");
          },
        }
      );
    } else {
      dislikeEventMutation.mutate(
        { id_events: item.id, id_user: id },
        {
          onSuccess() {
            queryClient.invalidateQueries();
            console.log("disliked");
          },
        }
      );
    }
  };

  return (
    <Ionicons
      onPress={() => {
        setIsFavorite((prev) => !prev);
        callApi();
      }}
      name={isFavorite ? "heart" : "heart-outline"}
      size={30}
      color={color} //
    />
  );
};

export default ButtonLikeEvent;
```

Every time an user click on that button I'd like to invalidate queries (because many screens shows the like button).

The console.log is displayed on success but the queries are not invalidate.

Any idea ?

thanks

Comment: I have "similar" issue but React Query Devtools is not helpful and even masking the problem, making it worse. With Devtools enabled, the invalidation works well. However without it, the invalidation doesn't work. So it becomes a Schrodinger's cat for me. React Query and React Query Devtools 5.12.2.

Comment: I tried to downgrade to React Query v4.x but still cannot make it work. Both with v4.x and v5.x React Query Devtools doesn't help me. And when a MUI Drawer opens, React Query Devtools suddenly clears all shown caches.

Comment: `await`ing `queryClient.invalidateQueries()` helped me

Answer (score 46):

I accidently used

```js
const queryClient = new QueryClient();
```

instead of

```js
const queryClient = useQueryClient();
```

`new QueryClient()` creates a new react-query Client(which is usually passed to a context wrapped over your App), this should be done only once.

wheres `useQueryClient` returns a reference to the value that the react-query Client context wrapped around your app provides. You should use it inside your components.

Comment: My exact problem. Thank you

Comment: can you even work with tanstack query properly when not doing this? :o

Comment: I had the same issue with Tanstack Query v5 and it worked like a charm.

`export const useContactDelete = () => {
  const queryClient = new QueryClient();

  return useMutation({
    mutationFn: (contactId) => deleteContact(contactId),
    onSuccess: async (res) => {
      // setQueryData
      await queryClient.invalidateQueries({
        queryKey: ["contacts", "list"],
      });

      await queryClient.invalidateQueries({
        queryKey: ["contacts", "info", res.id],
      });
    },
  });
};`

Answer (score 46):

Also, there is one more reason that was not mentioned before:

If you used `enabled` option in `useQuery` than such queries are ignored by `invalidateQueries`. From docs:

https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/react/guides/disabling-queries

> The query will ignore query client invalidateQueries and refetchQueries calls that would normally result in the query refetching.

Comment: This is exactly the answer I needed. Thank you so much!

Comment: This seems to be the reason for my troubles as well! How do I invalidate this hook then if `invalidateQueries` is ignored?

Comment: @bombillazo I don't know the suggested way, but I personally changed from useQuery to useMutation that makes a GET request.

Comment: Up to date link for react-query disabling-queries: https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/react/guides/disabling-queries

Answer (score 18):

The two most common issues why query invalidation is not working are:

- keys are not matching, so you are trying to invalidate something that doesn't exist in the cache. Inspecting the devtools helps here. Oftentimes, it's an issue with number/string (for example, if an id comes from the url, where it is a string, but in your key, it's a number). You can also try manually clicking the `invalidate` button in the devtools, so you will see that invalidation per-se works.
- the `queryClient` is not stable across re-renders. This happens if you call `new QueryClient()` inside the render method of a component that then re-renders. Make sure that the queryClient is stable.

Comment: Thank you for your insight. Unfortunately I can't use devtools as i'm using react-native. My queryClient is stable also as I'm declaring it in app.js.

Answer (score 10):

In my case, all I had to do was await the promise that `invalidateQueries` returns before navigating away (using react-router).

Comment: Me too. Wasn't aware it was a promise. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

In my case, invalidate queries didn't work because I tried to invalidate query that was used in another page (the useQuery that used this case wasn't rendered).

I had 2 options to solve this:

- use `refetchInactive` option like this: `queryClient.invalidateQueries(key, { refetchInactive: true })`, which will refetch the data instead of "stale" it.
- use `refetchOnMount: true` option when calling `useQuery`, which will refetch the data on mount regardless if it is stale.

Comment: Many thanks to this answer for the pointer to "inactive queries"! 
I was using TanStack Query + Router and trying out loaders in Router that would provide data for routes like `loader: () => await queryClient.ensureQueryData(/* query key and callback here */)`. But by default `invalidateQueries()` only forces refetch for **active** queries, and for some reason the loader doesn't count as being "active", so I had to add the prop `refetchType: 'all'` to `invalidateQueries()`.

Comment: Thank you. I have a similar case and I did `queryClient.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: ['key'], refetchType: 'all' }` using `v5.18.0`

Answer (score 5):

Both Samil and Eliav ideas combined worked for me:

1. QueryClient is only for initializing the QueryClientProvider.

```
const queryClient = new QueryClient();
```

2. useQueryClient is used everywhere else.

```
const queryClient = useQueryClient();
```

Answer (score 2):

QueryClient should be instantiated on the top of your app. (app.js or index.js)

Sample

```
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from 'react-query';

const queryClient = new QueryClient();
ReactDOM.render(
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
    <App />
    </QueryClientProvider>,
document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and in my case the problem was that I imported the wrong client.

I used vscode's autocomplete and accidentally imported it from `wagmi` instead of `@tanstack/react-query`.

[image]

Comment: Oh Wow, thank you. I was about to re-implement all the queries using my own hooks.
This issue is pretty annoying, it also happened once before with Mui theming, I was importing the wrong createTheme() function.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was trying to use the `queryClient` in a component with a higher level than the `QueryClientProvider` in the components tree. You have to use the `useQueryClient` hook in a component wrapped by the `QueryClientProvider`.

```html
<MyFirstComponent> <!-- I was using it in My FirstComponent. It is outside the QueryClient Context so it is not going to work there -->
  <QueryClientProvider>
    <MySecondComponent /> <!-- You can use the queryClient here -->
  </QueryClientProvider>
</MyFirstComponent>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case the **invalidateQueries** did not work after the app was **hot-reloaded** (after a change).

Very weird behaviour, but it takes a while before you figured out the hot-reloading is the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

When using `ensureQueryData` to retrieve data from cache if exist or fetching otherwise, one interesting challenge surfaced: the `invalidateQueries` method did not work for data invalidation .

Thankfully, `React Query` has a different `API` for this particular situation:

```
queryClient.removeQueries({ queryKey: ["queryKey"] });
```

Comment: might be not the most subtle touch for my case, but did the trick! :)

Answer (score 0):

An additional reason for why your queries might not be properly invalidating is if you aren't returning the promise-based function in `mutationFn`.

In my case, I made the mistake of calling the promise-based function without returning it. For example:

```
function useUpdateObject(id) {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();

  return useMutation({
    mutationFn: (newObj) => {
      // MISTAKE! Need to return ky.put(...)
      ky.put(API_ROUTE, { json: newObj }).json()
    },
    onSuccess: () => {
      queryClient.invalidateQueries({
        queryKey: ["object", id],
      });
    },
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem where everything was working correctly locally, but not in production. The issue was due to the cache of my Nginx server preventing data updates. To fix this, I had to add the directive

```
add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-cache' always;
```

to my Nginx server configuration.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I had:

```
const { isLoading, data } = useQuery(
  CACHE_KEY,
  async () => apiFunction(foo)
);
```

When in fact I needed:

```
const { isLoading, data } = useQuery(
  CACHE_KEY,
  async () => await apiFunction(foo)
);
```

Very subtle and easy to miss!

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** My issue was I incorrectly set up React Query as follows:

```
export default function App() {
  const queryClient = new QueryClient();
  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      ...
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
}
```

Fix:

```
const queryClient = new QueryClient();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      ...
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
}
```

Subtle, but changes everything.

---

My issue is that I have `react-router-dom`'s `useNavigate()` `.navigate()`, i.e.:

```
const router = useRouter();
router.push(`${path}?field=${name}`);
```

which either clears the cache or remounts components, but the important effect is the cache is cleared (can be observed through React Query Devtools).

Since the cache is cleared but the components stay, doing `invalidateQueries()` has no effect, as there's nothing on the cache.

It is the exact issue described here: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnreactjs/comments/uqd9sl/reactquery_cache_being_cleared_when_navigating/

I don't know how to solve this, so my "workaround" is to avoid using `navigate()` when possible. Although this is not ideal and I think I will get this issue again later. :'(

- react-query v5.12.2
- react-router-dom v6.16.0

Answer (score 0):

It seems like I have been dropped on my head in my childhood because I made a custom hook and spread the config props in the wrong way.

Do this:

```
const { onSuccess, ...restConfig } = config || {};

return useMutation({
  onSuccess: (data, variables, context) => {
    queryClient.invalidateQueries({
      queryKey: [productsQueryKeys.PRODUCTS],
      exact: true,
    });

    onSuccess && onSuccess(data, variables, context);
  },
  ...restConfig, <---- make sure you exclude the fields you're using
  mutationFn: createProduct,
});
```

Instead of this:

```
const { onSuccess } = config || {};

return useMutation({
  onSuccess: (data, variables, context) => {
    queryClient.invalidateQueries({
      queryKey: [productsQueryKeys.PRODUCTS],
      exact: true,
    });

    onSuccess && onSuccess(data, variables, context);
  },
  ...config, <---- who raised you like this?
  mutationFn: createProduct,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**WHEN USING SSR IMPLEMENTATION WITH NEXTJS 13**

When following the implementation enforced on TanStack's docs, you would be encouraged to create a request based client for Server Side and a singleton client for Client Side.

But when using `queryClient.invalidateQueries`, be sure to use queryClient from `useQueryClient` instead of importing your global client.

Here is an example of how to do it when invalidating in a mutation.

```
export const useAddProductToCartMutation = () => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();

  return useMutation({
    mutationFn: async (data: { productId: number }) => {
      return await addProductToCart(data.productId);
    },
    onSettled: async () => {
      queryClient.invalidateQueries({
        queryKey: ["cart"],
        refetchType: "all",
      });
    },
  });
};
```